# PubNub Tornado object initialisation raise exception

Tags: python-3.6, tornado, pubnub

I am using PubNub python Tornado SDK 4.2.1 with python 3.6
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python-tornado/api-reference-configuration

And I am trying to initialize `PubNubTornado` with following code,

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub_tornado import PubNubTornado
import os

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = os.environ['SUB_KEY']
pnconfig.publish_key = os.environ['PUB_KEY']
pnconfig.ssl = True

pubnub = PubNubTornado(pnconfig)
```

but it gives the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/exercise/pubnub_demo/initalize_demo.py", line 10, in 
>       pubnub = PubNubTornado(pnconfig)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pubnub/pubnub_tornado.py",
>   line 83, in **init**
>       self._telemetry_manager = TornadoTelemetryManager(self.ioloop)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pubnub/pubnub_tornado.py",
>   line 677, in **init**
>       self._timer.start()   File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 1209, in
>   start
>       self._schedule_next()   File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 1237, in
>   _schedule_next
>       self._update_next(self.io_loop.time())   File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 1244, in
>   _update_next
>       callback_time_sec *= 1 + (self.jitter * (random.random() - 0.5)) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'AsyncIOMainLoop' and
>   'float'

Comment: Can you repro with PubNub SDK logging enabled and provide the full log file? You might not want to share that publicly so feel free to open a [support ticket with PubNub](https://pubnub.com/support). Be sure to include the link to this post if you do so we know to answer back here when it is resolved. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python-tornado/pubnub-python-sdk-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Is this still an issue or did you find root cause and solution? Did you file with PubNub Support?